# How to remove network folders while preserving them at original place

Tags: windows-10

I have a Manjaro PC with Samba that shares my user's home folder, and a laptop running Win10. Recently I have tried the OneCommander file manager at the laptop: I created a new ("Favorite") place in OneCommander and changed it's path to my Samba location, say \MyPC\my_user. In the process it asked something like "Do you want to copy [something] to Desktop?". I supposed I answered "no", but it seems I really clicked "yes". Anyway I deleted it and now there are a lot of folders and files from the Manjaro home dir on my Win desktop, e.g. .ssh, .config, .bashrc etc. I cannot just delete them from the context menu because it will delete them on Linux PC too.

What the name of this objects (network folders, networks shortcuts)? And How to delete them preserving content on Linux machine?

**Update**: recently I noticed new tray icon - the icon of Sync Center. After googling a little bit I've found that those folders and files created by OneCommander are called "Offline files". So the first question is answered, I suppose. But I still have no success deleting them, what I've tried:

- Delete through context menu - it will delete files from Lnux machine as well.
- Disable offline files in Sync Center - offline files disappeared, but not deleted, they are still eat disk space.
- Delete through Sync Center - Sync Center -> Manage Offline Files -> View Your Offline Files. That opens Explorer with offline files, but 1) some of them has no name, 2) after I deleted them and restarted, they are still exist and syncing.
- I've found that actual location of offline files is `C:\Windows\CSC` (mine contains only folder `v2.0.6`). But I have no access to this folder - I've already tried to change permissions and the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution (not a perfect one though) [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ce9195f-0aea-4019-84e5-13bd01e36b19/cannot-remove-offline-files-from-sync-center?forum=w7itpronetworking).
How I already mention in a question post, I'have accidentally created a thing called "offline files". Normally this files controlled by Sync Center.

In two words you need to create key `FormatDatabase` of value `1` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Csc\Parameters` registry path. **NOTE**: the key should be of type `DWORD` (e.g. a 32-bit word), if you make it of type `QWORD` (e.g. a 64-bit word), you can get a permanent BSOD at reboot.

Normally, after system restart offline files should disappear. However I struggled with the following problems:

- After reboot files were removed and I disabled offline files through "Manage offline files". After reboot all offline files reappeared, but used disk space didn't increased. After a few disabling/enabling offline files and restarts, they finally seem to be gone (I hope).
- Sync Center said that offline files take ~102Gb of disk space, however after they were removed, only ~82Gb of free disk space was added.
- All my apps that were pinned to the taskbar disappeared. Also I was unable to pin any app again. Solved by a few reboots.

**Update**: Uh. After an half of hour of working, offline files suddenly showed again while I was pinning my apps to the taskbar. Free disk space is not decreased. Still I can't delete them through context menu - they appear again. Sync center is disabled.

**Update 2**: I asked MS support about my problem. Supporter suggested 2 option: 1) check for corrupted files with Windows utilities and 2) reinstall Windows.

First point didn't work, so I ended up with reinstall Windows)

Words of advice for young people: don't play with offline files and Sync Center until you prepared for consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the local copies on Windows should not delete their originals on Linux.

If you are worried - move these Windows files elsewhere, and only delete them
once you see that the Linux files were not harmed in any way.